# Is there any online tool to read (pronounce) IPA and APA written words?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, online-resources

I am looking for a tool to read a word written as phonetic transcription ([IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) or [APA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americanist_phonetic_notation)).

I need it to provide users with a tool to verify if they've chosen the correct IPA transcription (users will need to provide a word and its transcription, users are not experts in IPA and APA, so there should be an easy way for them to verify what they use).

Comment: It's a great idea. Let me know if you find one. Here's the nearest I have found. It does individual symbols. http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/

Comment: Since the same symbol in IPA is used for slightly different sounds in various languages, any tool like this won't be perfect. But it is a great idea.

Comment: Here: http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm

Comment: relevant questions on Linguistics SE: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/does-an-ipa-to-english-translator-exist, http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/is-there-an-online-tool-to-convert-ipa-symbols-into-audio-sound?lq=1

Comment: Oald has the pronunciation in IPA and an audio facility for BrE and AmE. See interpret:  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/interpret?q=interpret

Comment: @PeterShor Isn't the whole point of IPA that it represents sounds unambiguously?

Comment: @endolith: you would need over a hundred vowel symbols to represent sounds completely unambiguously. IPA has diacritics you put on vowels that tell you to raise, lower, back, or front them (showing that the ear can distinguish between many more vowels than the 25 or so basic IPA symbols for vowels) but these diacritics see relatively little use. So for example, /e/ may represent a slightly different sound in different languages.

Comment: @PeterShor Is there some other system that has the hundred vowel symbols?

Comment: @endolith: IPA with the diacritics probably has more vowel symbols than one would ever need.

Comment: I've always regarded the lack of such a tool as evidence that IPA isn't really all it's cracked up to be.

Comment: @endolith IPA is _in itself_ language-agnostic and deals only with phonetic, articulatory fact. So that is the system you’re looking for. The trouble is that when you start using it regularly to refer to any individual language, many of the finer details become moot and can be economised away as long as your readers know you’re using a less specified symbol to represent a given value in a language. It’s just laziness and practicality, though; you can always specify everything fully.

Comment: Full IPA is obnoxiously huge, but does represent all possible sounds in all languages. However, phonemes follow a normal probability distribution. The same distributions can be seen in infant babble globally. So, we don't have to concern ourselves with most sounds, most of the time. Members of language families tend to have similar phonemes with increased variety near metropolitan areas. All of this can be represented in IPA. The key would be building a database with clips of all possible vocalizations, starting with the most widely used. Call Google?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on ELU.Meta.

Comment: I voted to re-open so that the Q could get moved to meta, but apparently that is no longer possible due to age. Perhaps a friendly mod could migrate it?

Comment: @Cascabel_  and Edwin: The question attracted 80 upvotes and 105k views–ergo it must be useful–far more than it would ever get on meta. I say leave it be.

Comment: ELU.Meta is the place to request (and store) (**and find**) resource details. If _researchers_ can't find it or be bothered to look there ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's a very uncharitable comment, it's not whether people/users can be bothered to look for meta, it's 1) what the hell is meta? and 2) Meta? Where is it? You have to be naturally inquisitive to press all those icons and visit all the links. Not everyone is retired, not everyone finishes work at 5 p.m. ,not everyone can spare the time the amount of time necessary to explore. This site doesn't exactly explain that resources are in meta, many first-time users (perhaps all) only find out about meta when their question gets closed or migrated to that page.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A
 ELU's target audience is (and is spelled out to be) linguists and proficient Anglophones. If a question is migrated to ELU'meta, answers will probably still become available. The comment is intended as a reminder of already agreed site policy to seasoned users such as yourself. OP has had answers for many years.

Answer (score 26):

Sure! You can just use this tool

https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/

It works by translating ipa to sampa with lexconvert and than playing it with  meSpeak.js, that is a js clone of espeak.

Comment: I think most people can do better just approximating from the old Webster's-style pronunciation.  At least I found it incapable of pronouncing either "potato" or "apple", choosing IPA patterns from several different sources.  (I still find amazing that IPA, which is touted as being so much better than other schemes, does not have a decent pronunciation app.)

Comment: Maybe...for the English sounds. But I'm learning Czech and I'm quite desperate.

I agree, IPA should have an official and well-tested app

Comment: IPA was devised in the late 19th century; I doubt developing an app was foremost in their minds.

Answer (score 15):

I found this http://ipa-reader.xyz/ better than https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/

(Text is too short too post without this line)

Comment: Perhaps you could use the extra characters to say **why** it's better. For example, the different nationalities available give a hint as to how IPA is interpreted differently in different languages (which is something I found fascinating, playing with the site).

Comment: Yep, your first link pronounces "potato" (from Cambridge) far better than the github one.

Comment: Currently down :(

Answer (score 5):

There's a limited one available online, if you happen to have an Alexa Developer account.

1. Create an Alexa Skills Kit account.
2. Create a skill and fill out whatever fields you need to to enable the Testing tab (this isn't going to be easy).
3. Navigate into your skill by choosing your skill from https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html

Now that you are on the skill's page, if the `Testing` tab is clickable (Search for the word `Testing`), you can do the following each time you want to test:

1. Go to the `Testing` tab of your skill, and type something like this into the `Voice Simulator`:
   `<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="pɪˈkɑːn">pecan</phoneme>`
2. Click the `Listen` button

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#phoneme

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done this myself, but I think it should be possible:  first convert from IPA to SAMPA using [Phonverter - a converter between IPA and SAMPA transcriptions](http://www.lfsag.unito.it/ipa/converter_en.html) then [use MBROLA to pronounce the SAMPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBROLA).

An alternative is to use [lexconvert](http://ssb22.user.srcf.net/gradint/lexconvert.html) ([mirror](https://github.com/ssb22/lexconvert)) to do the conversion and feed the output to [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: last link is broken

Comment: The second one as well.

Comment: None of the link were broken - it may have been a network outage at your end.  However I've updated one link to point to Wikipedia which should have more longevity, and I've modified the text so that you can find all the applications by searching for their names.  This isn't the sort of stack exchange question where you can answer only by writing a description rather than linking, since the OP specifically asked for online tools.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two tools that can potentially help answer your need:

1. This tool reads aloud a word written as IPA phonetic transcription: https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/
2. This online converter will translate your text into its IPA phonetic transcription. It supports English and several other languages, and also reads your text aloud. 
   https://tophonetics.com

Additional helpful resources are: 
3. This [Interactive IPA chart](http://www.ipachart.com/)
4. The [General Phonetics page on Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/General_phonetics)
5. the [Help:IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA) page on the English language Wikipedia

Comment: The IPA tool in your first link does an incredibly poor job of pronunciation of even simple words.  Of course, it's likely that much of the problem is with IPA -- it's not all it's cracked up to be.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but this is a helpful tool. It allows you to hear what IPA symbols mean.

[IPA Learning Tool](http://web.mit.edu/6.mitx/www/24.900%20IPA/IPAapp.html)

Answer (score -2):

Here is what helped me:

- First, a video that shows pronunciation and mouth positions:
  https://youtu.be/-e66ByetpDY?list=PLlmgeS8moU5ggCOvV3x8MHZy7vY-wucdU
- Here is a site that has a table with sounds. You can click on them to hear and compare.
  http://web.mit.edu/6.mitx/www/24.900%20IPA/IPAapp.html

Best, Manfred

Answer (score -4):

https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/phonemic-chart-ia.htm

This has the sound as well. From my limited studies, I took a class on the history if English language, it seems legitimate.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a tool to pronounce words, not symbols..